# How can I mix between two rotations in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have one object (Object A) and a second object (Object B).

Object A's rotation is 0 degrees on the Y axis.
Object B's rotation is 720 degrees on the Y axis.

I want to blend between them in geometry nodes. I'm using an Object info node to get both their rotations and I'm plugging those into a Mix node set to "vector". I pipe the result of that mix node into a Transform Geometry node's rotation.

When I mix between them by setting the factor on the Mix node from 0 - 1 I dont get an object rotating from 0 to 720 degrees. Blender treats the 720 degrees as if it is 0 degrees. So no rotation happens.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: You can't get rotation outside of -180,180 range from object info.  You can't get rotation outside of -180,180 in a different space than the object's original ("relative" vs. "original"), period, not in any fashion.  If you want it from "original", use a value node with single property type driver (not transform channel type) to acquire the raw transform number of the object.

Comment: I just checked, what Nathan says is true throughout all Blender versions from 3.0 to and including 4.0. Blender 4.1. replaces blue socket with a new purple one, which is a quaternion rotation, and that one doesn't even give a possibility to express a rotation outside $(-180°, +180°)$ range (not sure about parentheses shape, the actual perfect values are not achievable at least not after converting from radians - maybe could be argued the actual quaternion can describe those angles)

Answer (score 3):

You can use drivers on the z-axis of your object. Let's say you have this setup

- Left empty at -20°
- Right empty at 370°

[image: Base setup with 2 emptys]

**Copy driver from 1st empty**

Right click on z-axis of rotation while having 1st empty selected, and *Copy as New Driver*.

[image: Copy driver]

**Paste driver in your geometry nodes**

In your *Mix* node, right click on z value of vector *A*, and *Paste Driver*.

[image: Paste driver]

**Repeat for 2nd empty**

Then repeat the same with the 2nd empty, copying its z-rotation as new driver and paste it in *B* vector in *Mix* node.

[image: Final mix node]